# How to extract text from a websites page?

Tags: python, html, selenium, beautifulsoup, scrapy

I am trying to extract text from some website's page whose HTML code looks like below. Sorry for the sorry looking code as I am a newbie and not aware of how to select a specific block of code in HTML.The code I have written below match somewhat with the actual code block as mentioned above.I am trying to extract the text which inside `p` tags as well as text inside `strong` tags under `h3` and in a manner that it would retain the order of the text as in the website's page.Upon inspecting each webpage I found that all texts are contained under `<div class=td-post-content>` but not all of them are just under `<p>` tags or `<strong>` tags,there can be other branch as `<p><strong><em>text</em></strong></p>` . Is there a way I can do this without manually extracting text for each and every webpage?(for reference I am mentioning the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffRP7.png) here)

```html
<div class="td-post-content">
  <p>some_text</p>
  <h3>
    <strong>some_text</strong>
  </h3>
  <p>some_text</p>
  <p>some_text</p>
  <p>some_text</p>
  <h3>
    <strong>some_text</strong>
  </h3>
  <p>some_text</p>
  <p>
    <strong>
      <em>text</em>
    </strong>
  </p>
  <p>'some_text'</p>
  <p>'some_text'</p>
 </div>
```

Comment: There is no one fits all solution if the "content text" is in website specific containers/tags - so you have to adjust your pattern depending on website structure.

Comment: I am trying to extract the text using `response.css('div.td-post-content p::text').extract()` but for `h3` I have to write the same code with `h3`, or is there a better way to automate it for other tags as well as I have to automate the task for the same website but for other articles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question you can do something like this:
Get all the elements inside `<div class="td-post-content">` element and then iterate over each element extracting it text.
In case there are another elements inside `<div class="td-post-content">`, not only `p` and `h3` containing the relevant texts - more filtration should be added here.

```py
all_elements = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, "//div[@class='td-post-content']//*")
for element in all_elements:
    print(element.text)
```